# What is the scope of a block?

Tags: ios, swift, realm, grand-central-dispatch

I have several functions that each perform some Realm related task. And another function that dispatches some sequence of those calls onto a background serial queue, like follows:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.CanHarveyDentBeTrusted", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)

func doStuff() {
    serialQueue.async {
        a()
        b()
        c()
        d()
        e()
        f()
    }
}
```

In this link: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1970, bdash says:

"Realm uses thread confinement for its objects, so you need to ensure that all work with a given object is performed on the same thread. **Since GCD doesn't guarantee that all blocks submitted to a given serial queue will execute on the same thread, you'll need to get a fresh Realm instance inside each block**."

So right now, functions a-f all create a Realm instance in a do try catch block, and then they do their own work with the realm object.

My question is, if I have a bunch of different sequences involving functions a-f, but all sequences will start with function a, can I have b-f force a realm creation?

From the Realm docs (https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest):

"Like any disk I/O operation, creating a Realm instance could sometimes fail if resources are constrained. In practice, this can only happen the first time a Realm instance is created on a given thread. **Subsequent accesses to a Realm from the same thread will reuse a cached instance and will always succeed**."

I don't know if doStuff() will dispatch all those calls as **one block**, with each a-f call being inside that one block. Or if each a-f call is in fact in their own individual blocks.

Because if they aren't all in the same block context, then I can't force realm creation in those calls, since they may not be running on the same thread, from my understanding.